# String is not equal to itself

Tags: php

But why?

```
if ('i' == 'і')
    echo 'good';
else
    echo 'bad';
```

echos:

```
>> bad
```

You should copy this snippet.  If you write it by hand, it will work.
It drives me crazy.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You are sneaky!  The second I is not a lower case latin small i.  I hexdumped it:

```
hexdump -C check
00000000  69 66 20 28 27 69 27 20  3d 3d 20 27 d1 96 27 29  |if ('i' == '..')|
00000010  0a 20 20 20 20 65 63 68  6f 20 27 67 6f 6f 64 27  |.    echo 'good'|
00000020  3b 0a 65 6c 73 65 0a 20  20 20 20 65 63 68 6f 20  |;.else.    echo |
00000030  27 62 61 64 27 3b 20 20  0a 0a                    |'bad';  ..|
0000003a
```

I'll let you look up D1 96 :-)  Awesome tricksy riddle.  +1

Comment: Yep, the right 'i' is Unicode character U+0456: `CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER BYELORUSSIAN-UKRAINIAN I`. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=%D1%96&preview=entity

Comment: Got it. It was input from user, and it was in English, so I didn't think that it is from other language.

Comment: Have an upvote to get your first "nice answer", this certainly deserves one.

Answer (score 8):

Delete the code and retype it :-)

There is an extra character or looks-alike nonsense in there (the `'i' == 'i'` bit).

[With a copy'n'paste -- "bad"](http://codepad.org/aAkEyINO)

[With the line replaced -- "good"](http://codepad.org/KTDpXzz4)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to prove `('i' != 'і')` visually!!

http://jsfiddle.net/naeDE/1/

```
<pre style="font-size:700%">
if ('i' == 'і')
    echo 'good';
else
    echo 'bad';
</pre>
```

Comment: +1 Although it depends on the font: for instance, in Safari, in the code in this answer, the two are indistinguishable to me, even at zoom. (Although in the fiddle they do appear different for me, right now, but this is not always the case.)