# Mongo regex query for field in list of embedded objects

Tags: regex, object, mongodb

i'm have a collection with records like this

```
> db.company.findOne({companyId:1})
{
"_id" : ObjectId("4e22ff08eefdd839f60ab95f"),
"lastUpdate" : ISODate("2011-07-11T17:00:00Z"),
"errorCount" : 0,
"house" : 49,
"phones" : [
    {
        "cityCode" : "3852",
        "number" : "461423",
        "type" : "phone"
    },
    {
        "cityCode" : "3852",
        "number" : "461317",
        "type" : "phone"
    }
],
"houseAdd" : "",
"rubricsId" : [
    NumberLong(184108177),
    NumberLong(184108175)
],
"companyId" : NumberLong(1)
}
```

now i'm try to find all companies with phone number start with 8-800
i'm try to search my query

```
db.company.find({"phones.number":/8-800.*/}
```

and get an empty list. But

```
db.company.find({"phones.number":/8.*/})
```

return all companies which phone numbers starts with eight.
AFAIK '-' isn't a special char for regex in this context? I'm try regex '8\-800' with same result.  Where's i'm wrong?

Comment: did you try escaping the dash (`8\-800.*`)? Maybe the mongo regex engine doesn't like dashes even if they are outside `[]`

Comment: Sorry, don't escape \ in my post. Edited.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the quotes. What happens if you use `/8.800.*/`? Are you sure that you have `phones.number` values that contain "8-800"?

Comment: @mu is too short - Thnx for good answer in any way! with /8.800.*/ i'm get an empty result :(. Yes, i'm know a companyId with phone 8-800-2000-245 and can see it with findOne by companyId

Comment: I'm using mongo 1.8.2, if it matter

Comment: Thanks for a visit to the MongoDB docs :) It is late where I am so I'm off. Try `/800/`, `/8.*800/`, and things like that, maybe you have some funny Unicode in your data (i.e. something that looks like a hyphen but isn't one).

Comment: YOU ARE COMPLETELY RIGHT!!! Pls post answer, and i'm vote for it! There was not '-', but '-'... Hmmm long '-', unicode long '-', which was hard to see in console, but when i'm dump my string in hex, i'm can see it.

Comment: I resurrected my old answer and updated it with the "funny Unicode" stuff.

Comment: @mu is too short: BTW, how you can see my visit to MongoDB docs? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have some funny Unicode in your data, just because it looks like a hyphen doesn't mean that it is a hyphen. You could try finding the entry you're looking for with `findOne` and then running the data through a hex dumper to see if it really is a plain ASCII hyphen or some Unicode thing that looks like a hyphen. If this is the case, then loosen up your search pattern to something like `/^8\W+800/` and tweak it until it finds exactly what you're looking for.

BTW, you're not the first person to come across tricky Unicode:

> [String is not equal to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639226/string-is-not-equal-to-itself/6639240#6639240)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
/^\D*8\D*800/
```

- `^` make sure that this is at the start of the string
- `\D*` any number of non-decimal characters, matches whatever you got between `8` and `800` (except numbers).

The first `\D*` might not be needed if you know that all those strings start with numbers and not anything else.